# how to get the "GDB OpenOCD Debugging" plug-in in Kepler Eclipse

Tags: gdb, eclipse-cdt, gdbserver, openocd

I am using latest version of Eclipse ie Kepler in that how to update/install the "GDB OpenOCD Debugging" plug-in tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the plugin here: http://gnuarmeclipse.livius.net/blog/plugins-install/

Just paste http://gnuarmeclipse.sourceforge.net/updates link into the "Work with:" field of the "Install new software" window of Eclipse (available from the Help main menu).

There are several components and GNU ARM OpenOCD Debugging Support is one of them.

But latest versions of OpenOCD work very well with the regular GDB Hardware Debugging.